# Send POST request from JavasScript to Sinatra endpoint

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, post, sinatra

so I have a javascript file that saves a specific value in a variable `send` that I need to send to my ruby routes file through a POST request. I'm a little confused if I can do this since what I have does not seem to work. I'm using the MVC structure so my routes file is saved in my `controllers` folder.

In my JS file, I have the following:

```
var send = "test"`
$.ajax({
    url : window.location.href + "senddata/",
    type : ",
    data : { send: send },
    }).done(function(response) {
       alert('1');
    }).fail(function (error) {
       alert('2');
    });
```

In my Ruby file, I'm not sure what to do to be able to receive this data? I know I need to do `@variable = params[:send]` but not sure from there. I'm using Sinatra.

My ruby code is as follows:

```
post '/senddata/' do
   flash[:success] = "Reached"
end
```

Comment: "Does not seem to work" is pretty non-specific, and you provide no information about the Sinatra side.

Comment: When I mean it doesn't seem to work, I mean nothing seems to be sending. I'll update my post with my ruby code

Comment: Checking if something is sending is easy enough; check the network tab. It's unlikely nothing is sending, though.

Comment: Is your Sinatra route at the root of the app? The URL on the client side is relative to the web app, not the web app's source code layout.

Comment: I'm quite new to all this, but I believe it isn't. The structure of the app is this route is in the controllers folder

Comment: The source layout of your application is irrelevant. If you don't have any nested routes the correct route would be `/senddata`, just like you defined it to be. You make Ajax requests to a web app, not to source code. You make GET requests via the browser's URL bar--what routes are you using to access your web app at all, and how are they similar/different to what you're trying to make an Ajax request to?

Comment: I get a 404 not found when I try to send the data. It seems to be using the URL `localhost:8000/controllers/data_routes/senddata` which is not an active URL on my web page

Comment: You're *telling* it to make a request to that URL--that's what the `url` property of the object passed to `$.ajax` is: the URL you are making a request to.

Comment: Thanks! So I've been modifying my code for the past few hours but am running into issues. I am sending a POST request using the url as 'window.location.href' and I get an alert of `1` indicating that the request was sent. When I open the network tab, I see that the data is being sent with a status code of 200. Now, the problem is in my ruby code (I've updated it), nothing seems to be running in the block for that post request - I get no flash message

Comment: You don't do anything with the response; what are you expecting to happen? Noting also that a flash message in an Ajax request is unlikely to do what you want anyway, although there's no way to understand what you're sending back by default anyway, because there's almost zero information about your Sinatra app in the question.

Comment: I want to eventually save the data being sent into a variable doing `@variable = params`, but at the moment just trying to get that code block to run so I can get some sort of feedback that it is executing, but seeing no flash message makes me think for some reason its not executing.

Comment: This use of `type` is nonsensical, btw; `type` isn't a URL, it's an alias for `method` (and not useful unless you're using a pre-1.9.0 jQuery).

Comment: Apologies, it was a bad edit on my part. I've re-updated the post with the correct edits

Comment: Where do you think you'd see it? You're *ignoring the response* to your Ajax request. You may want to consider taking a step back for a moment--there seem to be some fundamental misconceptions at play here.

Comment: It's also unclear why you'd build the request URL this way; unless you're at a pathless URL (like the index) you're just tacking on the `/senddata` path onto whatever is there, which is unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: The URL I'm trying to capture is the page I'm on (essentially I have a function where on an update to the page, an ajax request is sent). So I've made it both `url = window.location.href` and just `url = ''` to try it out, both of which yield the same results. The `/senddata` is yet another attempt at trying a different URL

Comment: So your browser bar reads something like `localhost:8000/senddata`? Okay. That makes a GET request to `/senddata`. If it's in your browser, presumably there's some sort of HTML send back. An *Ajax* request to `/senddata` should hit your POST route--but the *response* is handled by the `done` callback; if you have a template similar to whatever you do for your GET request it'll be part of the response object *in the JS* (also viewable in the network tab).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233763/discussion-between-dave-newton-and-flyingcitrus101).